# English translation of Gauss' "Principia generalia theoriae figurae fluidorum in statu aequilibri"

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I have been unable to locate an English translation of Gauss' work, "Principia generalia theoriae figurae fluidorum in statu aequilibri".

A German translation exists ([PDF](http://archive.org/stream/allgemeinegrund00gausgoog#page/n4/mode/2up)), but my German is not quite up to the task of translating it (nor is my rudimentary Latin sufficient to translate the original.)

Is anyone aware of an English translation of the full text?

Many thanks,

Christopher

Comment: there's only the German translation from 1903 (see also http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66682)

Comment: Eine gute Gelegenheit, um Deutsch zu lernen!

Comment: Stefan: Ich hab' nicht gesagt, dass ich kein Deutsch sprechen kann. Aber wenn ein Buch zweihundert Jahre alt ist, kann ich es nicht so gut verstehen :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike Mathscinet, Zentralblatt usually reviews translations. I checked Zentralblatt, and
found no translation of this work. So probably English translation does not exist. Actually
very few works of Gauss have been translated into Engish (I know only 2 or 3).

However I believe that there are two detailed expositions of this work:
In English: I. Todhunter, History of the mathematical theories of attraction and the figure
of the Earth, 2 volumes, 1873, Dover reprint 1962.
And in French: P. Appel, Traite de macanique rationnelle. Tome 4, Fasc. I. Figures d'equilibre d'une mass liquide homogene en rotation,
Paris, 1932.

Comment: Thank you, Alexandre. I will check out the English work you reference.